# File upload-download in its actual format

Tags: java, file, upload, download

I've to make a code to upload/download a file on remote machine. But when i upload the file new line is not saved as well as it automatically inserts some binary characters. Also I'm not able to save the file in its actual format, I've to save it as "filename.ser". I'm using serialization-deserialization concept of java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Your answers are useful. But I'm still having some problems. I'm able to upload only text files successfully. When I try to do the same for a word file it completely gets converted to a binary file. In text file also when I upload it adds some binary chars itself. Please note here i've not used serialization (ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream). For your reference soon I'll show you my code.

Comment: Here's my code: private static void upload() throws IOException,Exception { File upldfile = new File( (Path to the remote pc) + "/testSer.txt"); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(upldfile); File file = new File("c:/test1.txt"); FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()]; for(int j=0; j<file.length()-1; j++) { fis.read(b); } fos.write(b); fis.close(); fos.close(); } Lookig forward to your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you transmitting the files?  If you're using implementations of [InputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [OutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html), they work on a byte-by-byte level so you should end up with a binary-equal output.

If you're using implementations of [Reader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) and [Writer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html), they convert the bytes to characters according to some character mapping, and then perform the reverse process when saving.  Depending on the platform encodings of the various machines (and possibly other effects if you're not specifying the charset explicitly), you could well end up with differences in the binary file.

The fact that you mention newlines makes me think that you're using `Readers` to send strings (and possibly that you're stitching the strings back together yourself by manually adding newlines).  If you want the files to be binary equal, then send them as a stream of bytes and store that stream verbatim.  If you want them to be equal as strings in a given character set, then use Readers and Writers but specify the character set explicitly.  If you want them to be transmitted as strings in the platform default set (not very useful), then accept that they're not going to be binary equal as files.

---

(Also, your question really doesn't provide much information to solve it.  To me, it basically reads "I wrote some code to do `X`, and it doesn't work.  Where did I go wrong?"  You seem to assume that your code is correct by not listing it, but at the same time recognise that it's not...)

Comment: +1. He was undoubtely using `BufferedReader#readLine()`. It's the one which trims newlines. You don't want to do that on **binary** files.